# Tokio thread is not starting / spawning

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to start a new task to read from a socket client. I'm using the following same method on both the websocket server and client to receive from the connection.

The problem is, on the server side, the thread is started (2 log lines printed), but on the client side the thread is not starting (only the first line printed).

If I await on the spawn(), I can receive from the client. But then the parent task cannot proceed.

Any pointers for solving this problem?

```
  pub async fn receive_message_from_peer(
    mut receiver: PeerReceiver,
    sender: Sender<IoEvent>,
    peer_index: u64,
) {
    debug!("starting new task for reading from peer : {:?}", peer_index);
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        debug!("new thread started for peer receiving");
     // ....
    }); // not awaiting or join!()
```

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example please? It would greatly clarify what you are actually doing.

Comment: Can't seem to recreate the issue on a simple project. But if I call "tokio::task::yield_now().await;" after thread spawn called on parent task, 2 log lines are printed.

Comment: I'd say that you are blocking the tokio thread elsewhere, after calling `spawn`.

Comment: @rodrigo Will check on that. thanks

Comment: @SankaDarshana the fact that you can't recreate the issue on a simpler project means you haven't located yet where the issue lies. To help you with that, I would suggest you start by copying your entire new project elsewhere, start deleting stuff that you don't think is relevant and check is the bug is still present as you go. That's a bit long, but in the end it's very efficient IMO

Comment: Apparently the issue was that I was calling tokio::sync::mpsc::bounded::Receiver::try_recv() on a thread. Once I changed that to recv().await, it started working. Need to check more whether the issue was because of busy waiting or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the issue was I was using std::thread::sleep() in async code in some places. after using tokio::time::sleep() didn't need to yield the thread.

Comment: It looks like tokio uses only 1 thread and tries to share it across the multiple `async`-s. That's why the previous sleep didn't work for you. The same was the case with me. I now changed to `#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 4)]` which invokes all the `spawn`s even if i use `thread::sleep` every where

Answer (score 1):

Do you use tokio::TcpListener::from_std(...) to create a listener object this way?
I had the same problem as you, my std_listener object was created based on net2. So there is a scheduling incompatibility problem.
From the description in the newer official documentation https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.from_std, it seems that tokio currently has better support for socket2.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to `#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 4)]` as chendu suggested worked for me also.  In my case, on the embedded device I was trying to use, the main thread would never yield, and so jobs were never getting picked up.  Switching to multi-threaded, it all works correctly.